# Trying to understand how to complete and IFTHEN CHOOSE Formula in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, multi-function-printer

I am trying to test out a function of Excel that would allow me to do the following:

I want to be able  to select check  boxes  down a column. If a check box is selected I need 3 cells to populate in the same row as the selected check box. I then need to choose one of those 3 cells as a final value which will be put into the last column.

Right now I have it to where if a check box is selected column B changes from false to true but I don't know how to hide or show predetermined values and then force myself to select one to where it will add that value to any other row values of the same type for a grand total number at the end.

[image: Example for what I'm doing]

Comment: @MátéJuhász,,  thanks for the observation,, actually part of comment is typo,, it should ,,*This can be solved using VBA macro and also with FORMULA,* now I've corrected it ☺

Comment: This can be solved using VBA macro and also with FORMULA,, but the Macro would be better & faster,, confirm through comments which one suits you?